# Browser tabs keeps reloading when I press "L", and "J" has the same effect as Ctrl + F

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, drivers, keyboard, knowledge-management

This happens not only in Chrome, but also in Edge. I was using my laptop, but then I went away from keyboard and closed the lid, when I came back I tried to search for things in YouTube. But every time <kbd>L</kbd> was pressed, the site reloads, and anytime <kbd>I</kbd> press <kbd>J</kbd> the site will open the "find" utility. Happens on every site

I though it was a common error when windows sleeps, so I restarted. But the issue still persists. Then I restarted for 3 times. It still persists. Then I thought it may be a driver error so I uninstalled all keyboard drivers then restart my laptop. But when it turned on all the drivers are there and the issue still persists. So I tried checking for unusual apps in task manager but found nothing, all drivers are up to date

Using a key event tester it appears that those keys are the problem. Anything I can do other than windows reinstall?

[image: key event tester 1]

[image: key event tester 2]

anything i can do other than windows reinstall?

Comment: Is the problem only in YouTube? Do those keys work normally in other apps such as notepad?

Comment: nope on every app in this computer

Comment: Might be a stuck key, perhaps Ctrl.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean a keyboard problem.

Comment: i dont think so, the key event doesnt show any key being pressed on. and those keys dont work vice versa(e.g. j = F3 +  j, but F3 = F3), thats why i think this is on the software side. but i might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

so apparently it has been mysteriously fixed overnight. when I woke up this morning the power button was blinking even though it was not the night before, so I pressed spacebar to wake it up, but then the power button stopped blinking. and I tried to power it on, but it wont. so I thought it ran out of battery, so I plugged it in, and it turned on, but to my surprise it had 92% battery, which was rather impossible even in sleep mode given that this is a very power hungry laptop, 1 hour of browsing from 100% till it shut down, and at 50% in sleep mode went to 20% in 2.5 hours. keep in mind this laptop is 3+ years old at this point.

for those wondering, this is hp omen 15 early 2018 model

so the "fix" was to let it rest overnight

Comment: this doesnt really explain what happened, but its fixed, so should I accept this as an answer?